# Updating a map from a high-rate data flow

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have a multi-threaded Java application where a method [`update(key, value)]` updates a `ConcurrentHashMap`. For each key there will be more values received than can be put in the map and so once a key has been updated only the newest value of the threads waiting should be used to then update the map again. Or maybe there is some kind of lock that can be used where there is only ever 1 thread waiting - the one that has reached the lock last (effectively disposing of the thread already waiting)? It is important that the whole map is not locked which is why I haven't used a synchronized block around a normal `HashMap` as even if there are threads waiting on key A, key B should still be allowed to be updated as long as there are no threads already updating the value stored for B.

More succinctly, how do you update a map where key-value pairs are being received faster than updates can be made, using the last received value as the next update? So in the time A is updated to 1, values of 5, 3, 6, 8 are then received meaning the next update of A will be to 8.

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap is partly locked while doing any operations, basically it consists of multiple hashmaps that are locked. How many updating threads.

Comment: Map puts even into a ConcurrentHashMap are generally quite fast. I wonder if your problem really is with too many puts or maybe your equals/hashcode for the key are too complex? I hope this is a measured problem and not just a premature optimization based on a hunch.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was unclear - the problem is that we know we'll be receiving data too quickly to store every update, so how do we store an update then for the next update take the newest value that has been receieved? There is added complexity in that there will be updates for different entities (keys) hence the HashMap.

Comment: you mean *too quickly* to store the update in a hashmap alike structure? No a Database and any other IO access. I'd go w/ Mikko's idea: look at the hashing function (and use cached "int hash", if need be)

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult problem, and the root of the difficulty is in capturing the order in which the updates arrive.

If the updates *already* have an associated (fine grained) timestamp, then the solution is fairly straight-forward:

1. Define a `Value` class that hold the actual value and a timestamp.  It needs a synchronized `setIfNewer(ActualValue v, Timestamp t)` which updates the actual value if the supplied timestamp is more recent.
2. Define the map as `ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Value>`.
3. Use `putIfAbsent` to put values into the map.  If the `putIfAbsent()` returns a non-null value, use `setIfNewer(...)` to update it.

Note that this only works if the map updates can keep up *in the long term*; i.e. *average* data rate is not too high to cope with.

If the updates *do not* have an associated timestamp, then you've got a problem.  If you are having difficulty keeping up with the updates, then you will have difficulty adding an timestamp to the updates that accurately reflects the arrival time.  And that means that there is a risk that updates will be (in effect) reordered.  (If this is the case then I don't think the problem is solvable ... without changing the problem; see below.)

Some things that might work:

- Do some profiling / performance analysis to figure out where the bottleneck really is.  It might not be in doing the map updates at all.  (After all `ConcurrentHashMap` is designed to be highly scalable.)
- If there is strong affinity between the threads and the key values, then you could try 1) de-duping the updates in each thread using a per-thread LRU map, or 2) use a per-thread counter instead of a timestamp.
- You could try partitioning the map based on the keyspace.
- You could try adding more processors and/or more memory ... depending on what your profiling and monitoring are reporting.
- You could try partitioning the entire application based on the keyspace.  If the real problem is that the application cannot keep up, this may be the only possible approach.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no timestamp...and the average data rate is too high to keep up which is why of the values received for a particular key while it is being updated only the newest one should be then used to attempt another update. I thought of using a counter but I couldn't work out how it would identify the newest waiting thread and discard the other ones...

Comment: What are the actual data rates?

Comment: if you dont have a designated sequence/order of the elements, a simple AtomicLong will do, since if any thread is losing the CAS, one can assume the events occur in the same time.

Comment: I don't have any stats, I just know that we are receiving updates quickly enough in order that for a particular key we only need to be sampling the values received (ie. updating the map with the 1st value recieved, then the 5th, then the 8th...etc.) So in fact we don't want to keep up with the data rate, just need a a way of saying "ok we've finished updating that value, now we'll take the newest update and use that to update it again".

Comment: @Mathias - so in fact, you don't actually *know* that the bottleneck is in the map updating ... and not somewhere else in the code.  Correct?  I strongly advise you to do some profiling to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

How to do it?

There is a fairly simple solution to implement a sequencer, each object you add, needs a long field that's assigned upon construction w/ smth like AtomicLong.getAndIncrement().

update looks like that **and doesn't need sync**.

```
Class Value{
private static final AtomicLong sequencer = new AtomicLong()
final long seq = sequencer.getAndIncrement():
public boolean equals(Object o){
  //include seq as well :)
}
....
}
ConcurrentMap map;
for (Value cur;;){
    cur = map.get(key);
    if (cur==null){
        if (null==(cur=map.putIfAbsent(key, value))){
            break;
        }
    }           
    if (cur.seq>=value.seq){
        break;
    }
    if (map.replace(key, cur, value))
        break;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help with the problem of the high data rate we have though - I only want to sample the values being received, not use every value.

Comment: >>the problem is that we know we'll be receiving data too quickly to store every update<< if you mean this part. Well, I dont see a way to receive any data (and in so many threads) so quickly that the code above to be the bottleneck. Parsing the data, reading from sockets, etc is significantly slower. There is an optimized concurrent hashmap  (better than the one coming w/ JDK: http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib ). However, I do not believe you can receive such amounts of data.